# Segment violation in C

Tags: c, pointers, encryption

im coding a encryption engine, and when i try call to function "generar_clave", gcc say "segment violation", I new in C and need help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int clave[27];

typedef double t_clave;

t_clave claves[27][1000];
int clave[27];

char letras[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";



void generar_clave(int);
void ingresar_clave(int []);
int comprobar_repetir_vector(int, int []);
int comprobar_repetir_matriz(int, t_clave [][1000]);
void arrancar_motor(int, int);
int suma(int);


void main() {
printf("pruebas de snakecode\n\n");

generar_clave(20);

}

int comprobar_repetir_matriz(int numero, t_clave matriz[][1000]) {

    int x;
    int y;
    for(x=0; x<1000; x++) {

        for(y=0;y<27;y++) {

            if (numero==matriz[x][y]) {

            return 1;   
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

int comprobar_repetir_vector(int numero, int vector[]){

    int x;
    for(x=0; x<1000;x++) {

        if(numero==vector[x]) {

            return 1;

        }


    }

    return 0;



}


int suma(int numero) {

    int resultado=0;
    while (numero>0) {

        resultado+=numero%10;
        numero/=10;
    }
    return resultado;
}

void generar_clave(int numero_suma) {

    int maximo;
    int minimo;

    int max=120;
    int min=60;

    maximo=numero_suma*max/20;
    minimo=numero_suma*min/20;

    int x;

    int num_random;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("fuera del bucle");
    for(x=0;x<27;) {
        printf("dentro del bucle");
        num_random=minimo+rand() % (maximo+1-minimo);
        if (comprobar_repetir_vector(num_random, &clave[0])==1) {           
            continue;
        }
        clave[x]=num_random;
        x++;
    }

    int y;
    printf("se ha generado la clave: \n");
    for(y=0;x<27;y++) {

        printf("(%d)", clave[y]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}


void ingresar_clave(int array[]) {

int x;

for(x=0;x<27;x++) {

    clave[x]=array[x];
    }

}

void arrancar_motor(int numero_cifras, int cantidad_numeros){

    char max[1000];
    char min[1000]="1";

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int h;
    int num_random;

    for(x=0; x<numero_cifras; x++) {

        strcat(max, "9");

    }

    for(y=0; y<numero_cifras-1; x++) {

        strcat(min, "0");

    }

    int maxi=atoi(max);
    int mini=atoi(min);


    for(z=0; z<27; z++) {
        printf("Inicializando letra %s", letras[z]);
        for(h=0; h<cantidad_numeros;) {
            num_random=mini+rand() % (maxi+1-mini);
            if ((suma(num_random)==clave[z]) && (comprobar_repetir_matriz(num_random, claves))==0) {

                claves[z][h]=num_random;
                printf("%d", num_random);
                h++;



            } else { continue;  }


        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried everything and can not find the way that works, also applies to the engine, apart from this failure, is still to finish, it is a very simple algorithm, I wrote in python long ago and wanted to port it to C for learn C.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: Please provide a ___[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)___

Comment: _Too much code_! Please reduce it. I'm quite sure GCC points to the line number where the error occurs.

Comment: @ForceBru if not `gcc`, `gdb` will do that for sure, provided the `-g` option enabled.

Comment: Why do people write code in their native language?... it looks so awkward

Comment: @andreee its mostly newcomers who do that ... they will learn, and they will adapt sometime.

Comment: You should only call srand once, at the beginning of the program. So you shouldn't include it in your functions that perform various algorithms.

Comment: You are calling the function `comprobar_repetir_vector` and passing in the address of the array `int clave[27]`, but inside the function you are iterating over 1000 elements of the passed-in array. Maybe you meant to pass in `t_clave claves[27][1000]` instead, although the types don't match? Also, as @sourav-ghosh mentioned, learning about the `gdb` debugger, or another debugger depending on your development environment, would also be good.

Answer (score 3):

```
char max[1000];
char min[1000]="1";

int x;
int y;
int z;
int h;
int num_random;

for(x=0; x<numero_cifras; x++) {

    strcat(max, "9");
```

`strcat` appends a copy of the source string to the destination string, `max` must be a NUL terminated string:

```
char max[1000] = {0};
```

And in this line:

```
printf("Inicializando letra %s", letras[z]);
```

you want to print a `char` (not a string), use:

```
printf("Inicializando letra %c", letras[z]);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I changed the mistakes you've written but still gives the same error.